# AddressBook - How do I compare two compound names

Tags: java, addressbook

I have to make an address book for a school project. I got the basic functions working but then we are asked the following.

"Using the get and set methods, create a comparison method compareNames(name1, name2) that compares the first, middle, and last names of strings name1 and name2. Assume that name1 and name2 follow the following format: “FirstName M. LastName”."

I have a Data class:

```
public class Data {
private String firstName = null;
private String middleName = null;
private String lastName = null;
private String homeAddress = null;
private String businessPhone = null;
private String homePhone = null;
private String cellPhone = null;
private String skypeId = null;
private String facebookId = null;
private String personalWebSite = null;

public Data(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String homeAddress, 
        String businessPhone, String homePhone, String cellPhone, String skypeId, 
        String facebookId, String personalWebSite) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
    this.homePhone = homePhone;
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    this.skypeId = skypeId;
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
    this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getmiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String gethomeAddress() {
    return homeAddress;
}

public void sethomeAddress(String homeAddress) {
    this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
}
public String getbusinessPhone() {
    return businessPhone;
}

public void setbusinessPhone(String businessPhone) {
    this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
}
public String gethomePhone() {
    return homePhone;
}

public void sethomePhone(String homePhone) {
    this.homePhone = homePhone;
}

public String getcellPhone() {
    return cellPhone;
}

public void setcellPhone(String cellPhone) {
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
}

public String getskypeId() {
    return skypeId;
}

public void setskypeId(String skypeId) {
    this.skypeId = skypeId;
}

public String getfacebookId() {
    return facebookId;
}

public void setfacebookId(String facebookId) {
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
}


public String toString() {
    return String.format(firstName+" "+middleName+" "+lastName+"  "+homeAddress+" "
            +" "+businessPhone+" "+homePhone+" "+cellPhone+" "+skypeId+" "
            +facebookId+" "+personalWebSite);
}
}
```

And an AddressBook class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddressBook {
private static List<Data> contact = new ArrayList<Data>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menu;
    String choice;
    String name1;
    String name2;
    String name3;

    System.out.println(" 0. Exit. ");
    System.out.println(" 1. Add contact. ");
    System.out.println(" 2. Edit contact. ");
    System.out.println(" 3. Compare contact ");
    System.out.println(" 4. Outprint contact. ");
    System.out.println(" 5. Outprint all contacts. ");
    System.out.println(" 6. Delete contact. ");

    menu = sc.nextInt();

    while (menu != 0) {

        switch (menu) {

        case 1:
            while (menu != 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
                String firstName = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Middle Name: ");
                String middleName = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
                String lastName = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Home Address: ");
                String homeAddress = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Business Phone: ");
                String businessPhone = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Home Phone: ");
                String homePhone = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Cell Phone: ");
                String cellPhone = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Skype ID: ");
                String skypeId = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Facebook ID: ");
                String facebookId = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Personal Web Site: ");
                String personalWebSite = sc.next();
                contact.add(new Data(firstName, middleName, lastName,
                        homeAddress, businessPhone, homePhone, cellPhone,
                        skypeId, facebookId, personalWebSite));// Creating a
                                                                // new
                                                                // object
                                                                // and
                                                                // adding it
                                                                // to list
                System.out
                        .println("Would you like to add someone else? 1: Yes, 2: No");
                menu = sc.nextInt();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out
                    .println("Enter First Name of contact that you would like to edit: ");
            choice = sc.next();
            addressBook.deleteByFirstName(choice);
            System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
            String firstName = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Middle Name: ");
            String middleName = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
            String lastName = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Home Address: ");
            String homeAddress = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Business Phone: ");
            String businessPhone = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Home Phone: ");
            String homePhone = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Cell Phone: ");
            String cellPhone = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Skype ID: ");
            String skypeId = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Facebook ID: ");
            String facebookId = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Personal Web Site: ");
            String personalWebSite = sc.next();
            contact.add(new Data(firstName, middleName, lastName,
                    homeAddress, businessPhone, homePhone, cellPhone,
                    skypeId, facebookId, personalWebSite));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out
            .println("Enter First Name of the first contact that you would like to compare: ");
            name1 = sc.next();
            for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Data temp = iterator.next();
            System.out
            .println("Enter First Name of the first contact that you would like to compare: ");
            name2 = sc.next();
            for (Iterator<Data> iterator2 = contact.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
                Data temp2 = iterator2.next();

                    System.out.println(temp);
                    System.out.println(temp2);

                    if (name1.compareTo(name2) == 0) {
                        System.out.println("The strings are equal.");
                    } else if (name1.compareTo(name2) < 0) {
                        System.out.println("name2 follows name1");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("name1 follows name2");
                    }
                    return;
                }


            System.out.println("No contact with first name " + name1
                    + " and/or " + name2 + " was found.");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out
                    .println("Enter First Name of contact that you would like to print: ");
            choice = sc.next();
            addressBook.searchByFirstName(choice);
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("This is a list of every contact");
            System.out.println(addressBook.contact);
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out
                    .println("Enter First Name of contact that you would like to delete: ");
            choice = sc.next();
            addressBook.deleteByFirstName(choice);
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(" 0. Exit. ");
        System.out.println(" 1. Add contact. ");
        System.out.println(" 2. Edit contact. ");
        System.out.println(" 3. Compare contact ");
        System.out.println(" 4. Outprint contact. ");
        System.out.println(" 5. Outprint all contacts. ");
        System.out.println(" 6. Delete contact. ");
        menu = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");

}

private void addData(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName,
        String homeAddress, String businessPhone, String homePhone,
        String cellPhone, String skypeId, String facebookId,
        String personalWebSite) {
    Data person = new Data(firstName, middleName, lastName, homeAddress,
            businessPhone, homePhone, cellPhone, skypeId, facebookId,
            personalWebSite);
    contact.add(person);
}

private void searchByFirstName(String firstName) {
    for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Data temp = iterator.next();
        if (temp.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("No contact with first name " + firstName
            + " was found.");
}

private void deleteByFirstName(String firstName) {
    for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Data temp = iterator.next();

        // Add null checks for proper error handling.

        if (temp.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
            iterator.remove();
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("No contact with first name " + firstName
            + " was found.");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on what you want to compare and what you want the output to be?

Comment: What is wrong with "return name1.equals(name2);" or "return name1.compareTo(name2);"?

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the names in the specified format from the `Data` instances and compare these two strings in whatever way you are supposed to do.

```
public String formatForComparison(Data data){
      String result = "";

      result += data.getFirstName() + " ";
      result += data.getMiddleName().charAt(0) + ". ";
      result += data.getLastName();

      return result;
}
```

NOTE: this will only work, if a second name with atleast one char is **always** given.